# CSS table affecting my Navigation bar which is also a table

Tags: html, css

My problem is I'm trying to create a table in CSS without it affecting my navigation bar which has been created as a table in Fireworks. I've tried targeting the table using ID and class selectors but that didn't work.

This is the table I want to create in **CSS**:

```
.cart table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: #999;
    font: 80%/1.2 'Arvo', serif, sans-serif, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times,serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.cart table th, td {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    padding: .5em;
}

.cart table tr {
    background: #B0C4D7;
}

.cart table thead th {
    background: #fff;
    color: #fff;
}

.cart table th {
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #fff;
}

.cart table tr.alternate {
    background: #fff;
}

.cart table tr.alternate th {
    background: #fff;
}
```

The **HTML** code:

```
<div class="cart">
    <table>      
............ info here etc.............
    </table>
</div>
```

The navigation bar **CSS** is:

```
#navigation {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 860px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

And the navigation **HTML** is:

```
<div id="navigation">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="780">
   <!-- fwtable fwsrc="navbar.png" fwbase="navbar.gif" fwstyle="Dreamweaver" fwdocid =    
      "820939584" fwnested="0" -->
   <tr>
      <td><img name="navbar_r1_c1" src="images/navbar/navbar_r1_c1.gif" width="78" 
         height="30" border="0" alt=""></td>
      <td><a href="index.html" target="_self" onMouseOut="MM_nbGroup('out');" 
         onMouseOver="MM_nbGroup('over','navbar_r1_c2','images/navbar/navbar_r1_c2_f2.gif',  
         'images/navbar/navbar_r1_c2_f4.gif',1);" 
         onClick="MM_nbGroup('down','navbar1','navbar_r1_c2',  
         'images/navbar/navbar_r1_c2_f3.gif',1);"><img name="navbar_r1_c2" 
         src="images/navbar/navbar_r1_c2.gif" width="66" height="30" border="0" alt="home"></a>
      </td>
      ..... more cells etc.........
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get it right - is the navigation table not in the .cart `<div>` element, and vice versa?

In addition, this rule is problematic:

```
.cart table th, td { ... }
```

You need to change it to:

```
.cart table th, .cart table td { ... }
```

Comment: Yes that's right the navigation table is not in the .cart <div> element. And I'll try your suggestion. Thanx

Comment: @BenBazzoni I'm glad it worked. Do accept the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: I copied and pasted the code from a book CSS in 10 minutes by Russ Weakley. This is the second time I've found a mistake in the book. What hope is there for beginners if you can't trust the books your reading.